# Download ICS String into Mobile with Javascript (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, icalendar

I'm creating a ics string in my app with this code:

```
var icsMSG = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:-//Our Company//NONSGML v1.0//EN\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nUID:me@google.com\nDTSTAMP:" + today
icsMSG = icsMSG + "\nATTENDEE;CN=My Self ;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:me@gmail.com\nORGANIZER;CN=Me:MAILTO::me@gmail.com\nDTSTART:" + start +"\nDTEND:" + end +"\nSUMMARY:" + $scope.eventContent.text + "\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR";
```

This is working fine, since when I want to download on my PC it works fine.
For downloading in PC I'm using

```
window.open( "data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG));
```

Apparently this does not work on mobile. On iPhone it does not recognize the file, in Android it downloads the file and you must open it to add to calendar.

I read about `webcal://` But it seems to not work sending the string after the `webcal://`

How can I set the download click in mobile

Answer (score 0):

The spec-compliant newline sequence is `\r\n`.  I doubt that's the problem, but you could try it.

Also, you could try `charset=utf-8` (add the dash).

Also note that you have an extra colon character in one of your "mailto" URIs.